# Submitted data aren't stored in the database

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my current spring-boot project, I have a page built with Thymeleaf, where I have a form like that:

```
<form class="form" role="form" method="post" th:action="@{/__${command.getClass().getSimpleName()}__/cadastra}">
   ...
</form>
```

which is rendered to this:

```
<form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="/Usuario/cadastra">
    ...
</form>
```

the problem happens when I try submit the form: the following error is triggered:

```
error: "Internal Server Error"
exception: "org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException"
message: "Error resolving template "Usuario/cadastra", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers"
path: "/Usuario/cadastra"
status: 500
timestamp: 1417225370311
```

in the console, this is displayed:

```
2014-11-28 22:42:50.303 ERROR 32286 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template "Usuario/cadastra": Error resolving template "Usuario/cadastra", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
2014-11-28 22:42:50.305 ERROR 32286 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "Usuario/cadastra", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "Usuario/cadastra", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:245)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

anyone can see what's the problem here?

PS.: the handler for the submitted data is this controller method:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public void cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    serv.cadastra(object);
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I solve the error above adding the annotation @ResponseBody to the method in controller, but now I have another issue: despite no more errors are being displayed, the submitted data isn't saved in the database (same occurs if I try update or remove the object).

The methods in controller which handle this operations are:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    serv.cadastra(object);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "altera", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void altera(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    serv.altera(object);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "remove", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void remove(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    serv.remove(object);
  }
```

In my service class:

```
  @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
  @Transactional
  public void cadastra(E object) {
    dao.insert(object);
  }

  @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'altera_'+#this.this.name)")
  @Transactional
  public void altera(E object) {
    dao.update(object);
  }

  @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'remove_'+#this.this.name)")
  @Transactional
  public void remove(E object) {
    dao.delete(object);
  }
```

and in my Dao class:

```
@Transactional
public void insert(E object) {
    getEntityManager().persist(object);
}

@Transactional
public void update(E object) {
    getEntityManager().merge(object);
}

@Transactional
public void delete(E object) {
    getEntityManager().remove(object);
}
```

what's wrong now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this pŕoblem using this structure to the methods of my dao class:

```
public void insert(E object) {
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(object);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Comment: I don't think that @Transactional is properly configured. You shouldn't be able to begin and commit user managed transactions. Are you autowiring the Service on the Controller? The error says that "The problem is that the template is missing" as Dave said. Do the controller have @RequestMapping("Usuario")? Or try annotating the method with @RequestMapping("Usuario/cadastra")

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the template is missing. If your template is in a different location than the default you need to to return a String from your `@RequestMapping`.